# How to prevent printing variables in view helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, viewhelper

I have an array, which is loaded from a database. It is in the following format:

```
["aaa:bbb", "ccc:ddd"]
```

And need to build an HTML definition list from the array:

```
<dl>
  <dt>aa</dt>
    <dd>bb</dd>
  <dt>cc</dt>
    <dd>dd</dd>
</dl>
```

Looks easy, isn't it?

I wanted to create a helper, which would go through the array, split the items on the `:`'s,  and enclose them in tags:

```
<%= build_def_list(array) %>
```

However, I have encountered a problem. Namely, when I call a Rails helper from a view, all of its content goes to the output. That is, when I declare a variable within the body of a function and assign a value to it, the variable instantly goes to the output. Is there a way to suppress the printing of everything inside the body of a function?

**UPD**

Seriously, how to make this with helper?..

```
<dl>
    <% deflist.each do |item| %>
          <dt><%= item.split(':').at(0) %>:</dt>
            <dd><%= item.split(':').at(1) %></dd>
    <% end %>
</dl>
```

Comment: What is the rule that extracts `"aa"` and `"bb"` from `"aaa:bbb"`, and so on?

Comment: "aaa" == dt, "bbb" == dd. Simple split by :

Comment: That is not what your code shows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your helper:

```
def build_def_list(array) 
  content_tag :dl do 
    array.map { |e| e.split(':') }.collect do |dt, dd| 
      content_tag :dt, dt
      content_tag :dd, dd
    end
  end 
end
```

Then in your view call `<%= build_def_list(array) %>`

**Addition:** (To filter what to print)

Thanks to @Arup who reminded me the additional check:

> How it would prevent printing all?

To print only specific items, you can filter your input array first deleting any elements you need to remove then use the resultant array to build the `content_tag`s as:

```
def build_def_list(array) 
 reject_keys = ['ccc'] 
 array = array.map { |e| e.split(':') }.reject { |e| reject_keys.include? e[0] }

 content_tag :dl do 
    array.collect do |dt, dd| 
      content_tag :dt, dt
      content_tag :dd, dd
    end
  end 
end
```

This will first split the elements of the `array` by `:` and delete all the elements if they are found in `reject_keys` array.  The result is then used to build the `content_tag`s.

Comment: How it would prevent printing all?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, thanks for that.  I didn't see that initially.  Updated my answer to include the filtering.

Comment: This code prints empty dl

Comment: @br., sorry there was a missing brace before `reject` call.  That should have thrown an error.  Please try this again.

Comment: already fixed, but nothing changed

Comment: Please post your input array and the reject array.

Comment: i don't need to reject items, i need build definition list from array. but in fact i need to make custom output. But i can't use variables and cycles, because they printing out.